# Forward incoming call to free extension

Tags: asterisk

I have configured asterisk and dahdi successfully in Centos 7.

My Incoming and Outgoing calls are working good.

But I have one problem configuring extensions.conf for incoming.

I have this code in extensions.conf for incoming

```
[from-pstn]
exten => _X.,1,Noop(Incoming call "from PSTN")
same =>   n,Dial(SIP/206)
same =>   n,Hangup()
```

It is currently forwarding all incoming calls on extension 206, but I want it to forward to those extension which are not on any call this time.

Any idea/help is appericiated

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have extensions 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, and 206.

The DIAL command will let you call more than one device at once.  So, you could do something like this:

```
[from-pstn]
exten => _X.,1,Noop(Incoming call "from PSTN")
same =>   n,Dial(SIP/201&SIP/202&SIP/203&SIP/204&SIP/205&SIP/206)
same =>   n,Hangup()
```

Alternately, and just as effective, you could use Asterisk's call queues / ACD system.  See the link below.

Further reading:

- https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Application_Dial
- https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Building+Queues